# Triangular Inequality involving binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given $a,b,c,n\in\mathbb{N}^+$, and $a,b<c$, in which conditions does the relation

> $$
> \binom{a+n-1}{n}+\binom{b+n-1}{n}\geq\binom{c+n-1}{n}
> $$

hold?

Since I am not an expert in this field, I beg your pardon in case the question is too trivial (or too complex)! Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The problem is more appealing if we further suppose $a+b>c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ n=1$, then $$\binom{a+n-1}{n}+\binom{b+n-1}{n}\geq\binom{c+n-1}{n}\iff  a+b\ge c $$

which does not have to be true.

Thus $$a\le b<c $$ is not sufficient for $$\binom{a+n-1}{n}+\binom{b+n-1}{n}\geq\binom{c+n-1}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Perhaps my OP was not clear (and I edit it), but I am actually asking _in which conditions_ the inequality holds, I am not claiming any implication. The hypothesis $a,b<c$ is imposed only to avoid the obvious cases  $a>c$ and/or $b>c$, for which the inequality is obviously true. Any suggestion how to improve the question? Thanks again!