# Summing combinations with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, functional-equations

Given $m,n,k\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,...\}$, I wonder if it is possible to find a $F:\mathbb{N}^3\to \mathbb{N}$ such that

> $$
> \binom{m+k-1}{k}+\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{F(m,n,k)+k-1}{k}.
> $$

EDIT: A more reasonable version of the problem (inspired by the smart observations below) is to find, for each $k$, a different function, say $F_k(m,n)$, such that $
\binom{m+k-1}{k}+\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{F_k(m,n)+k-1}{k}$. For instance, for $k=1$, we have $F_1(m,n)=m+n$.

Thanks for your help!

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2841171/559615.

Comment: So $k$ is fixed natural? And numbers are >0?

Comment: Yes. I edit it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Angle I had to edit the post. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if such $F$ exist, then $k=1$ since for $m=n=1$ we have

$$2{k\choose k} = {F(1,1)+k-1\choose k}\implies F(1,1)=2\;\; \wedge\;\; k=1$$

(remember Pascal triangle and only possibility where 2 stands) so $$
\binom{m}{1}+\binom{n}{1}=\binom{F(m,n)}{1},
$$

So $F(m,n) = m+n$.

Comment: I see. but then I have to modify the post. The question is not well posed.

Comment: But that is another question! You should post as another question. Any way, the answer and the solution are the same.

Comment: I post it as another question then. Just, What do you mean with "the Answer is the same"? This should be true only for $k=1$, right? Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Actually, in that case function don't exist. It exist only if $k=1$ as you previously posted.

Comment: Please, can you explain me why? I have difficulties to see this! Thanks!

Comment: Whole thing in my answer changes only to $F(1,1,k)$ where $k$ is arbitrary. But from formula we get that $k$ must be 1. A contradiction.

Comment: You mean it should be a _different_ function of $m,n$ for each $k$? In this case I can reshape the post in a more meaningful way...

Answer (score 0):

Given for ascertained that it cannot be $F(m,n)$, but the it shall be $F(m,n,k) as in your new edition of the post,
then,using the [Falling and Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) definition of the binomial, your identity can be rewritten as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( \matrix{  m + k - 1 \cr   k \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{  n + k - 1 \cr   k \cr}  \right)
 = \left( \matrix{  F(m,n) + k - 1 \cr   k \cr}  \right)\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad {{\left( {m + k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}} + {{\left( {n + k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}
 = {{\left( {F(m,n,k) + k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } } \over {k!}}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad m^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  + n^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = F(m,n,k)^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  \cr} 
$$
where
$$
x^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = \left( {x + k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} }  = {{\Gamma (x + k)} \over {\Gamma (x)}}
$$
denote respectively the Rising Factorial, the Falling Factorial  and their relation with the Gamma function.

Now, if we want $F$ to be an integer, the last line looks as the analoguous for the Rising Factorial
of the Fermat's Last Theorem identity, and I expect (although I am not in the position to prove it) that it might
subject to the same ban.

Looking more modestly for a real $F$, then we are facing with the inversion of the Gamma function, which does not have
an easy formulation.

On the other hand $z^{\,\overline {\,k\,} } $ is a polynomial in $z$ of degree $k$
$$
z^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = z\left( {z + 1} \right) \cdots \left( {z + k - 1} \right)
  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,l\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left[ \matrix{ k \cr   l \cr}  \right]x^{\,l} } 
$$
where the square brackets indicates the [Stirling Numbers of 1st kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number).

The equation 
$$
z^{\,\overline {\,k\,} }  = a
$$
has always a unique non-negative solution in $z$ for non-negative values of $a$, but to find
it we shall resort to numerical computation, or to the various asymptotics approximations for 
Gamma and Factorials.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying to metabolize your nice answer. What I would need to study is here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2841111/559615. Perhaps that request is less hard than this one. Can you have a look? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I wonder if we can find a countable set of functions to address the "exact" problem, e.g.  as $F_k(m,n)$. For instance, following the answer of @Angle, it should be $F_1(m,n)=m+n$. But maybe I have to modify the post...

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: the subject is quite interesting: I will deepen on it.

Comment: Thanks you very much! Let me know your view.

Comment: @andrea.prunotto: I recasted my answer. Unfortunately there is not an "easy" solution, nor an approximation valid in general (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: *No, such a function does not exist.*

Consider the case of $k=2$. We have $\binom 42=6$. But $\binom n2\neq12$ for all $n$. This means that $F(3,3,2)$ does not exist.

It is easy to construct more similar examples based on the fact that the set of binomial coefficients $S(k)=\{\binom nk\mid n\in\Bbb{N}\}$ is not closed under addition.

May be you wanted to ask some other question?

Comment: Thanks for your observation! Yes, I am also doubtful about this question, sorry for my naivety. I wonder if we can build a countable class of functions, such as $F_k(m,n)$, generated by the request. For instance (after the answer of @Angle) it should be $F_1(m,n)=m+n$. Do you think that this question is more meaningful?

Comment: Actually, I am more interested in finding whether is holds the inequality $\binom{m+k-1}{k}+\binom{n+k-1}{k}\geq \binom{c+k-1}{k}$ (or its opposite), when $m,n<c$.

Comment: Another motivation is that we can write $\binom{a+n-1}{n}+\binom{b+n-1}{n}-\frac{a+b-c}{n}=\binom{c+n-1}{n}$ which, for n=2 is true for all the Pythagorean triplets $a,b,c$. Hence, a connection with Fermat's theorem (?). The term $-\frac{a+b-c}{n}$ should be entailed somehow in these $F_n(a,b)$. I would like to understand if we could write it in a general form of a combination such that $\frac{a+b-c}{2}=\binom{x+n-1}{2}$ is just a special case.

Comment: ... but this should be another post! : )