# Partitions of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given a number of trials $n>1$, which conditions must the integers $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}^+$ satisfy in such a way that it holds the following relation?

> $$
> \binom{a+n-1}{n}+\binom{b+n-1}{n}=\binom{c+n-1}{n}+\binom{d+n-1}{n}
> $$

The problem is inspired by the fact that, with $n=2$, $a+b>c$, and $$d=\frac{-3+\sqrt{4(a+b-c)+1}}{2},$$
 the relation is satisfied by all the Pythagorean triplets $a,b,c$.

**EDIT:** The problem is clearly interesting only in case of non-trivial solutions (e.g. the relation certainly holds in case $a=b$ and $c=d$).
See also [Summing combinations with repetition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2841633/559615) and [Triangular Inequality involving binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2841111/559615).

Since I am not an expert, I apologize in case this is an obvious problem.

Comment: Well, it certainly holds if $\{\,a,b\,\}=\{\,c,d\,\}$.

Comment: True! :) I edit it!

Comment: I suspect that for $n\ge5$ it has very few, if any, nontrivial solutions.

Comment: this is clearly tied to your [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841633) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841111) on  similar subject

Comment: True. I forgot to add the links. I edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at $n=2$. We have $${r\choose2}+{s\choose2}={t\choose2}+{u\choose2}$$ Multiply both sides by 8 and add 2 to get $$(2r-1)^2+(2s-1)^2=(2t-1)^2+(2u-1)^2$$ So we're asking for numbers expressible in more than one way as a sum of two odd squares. For example, $130=11^2+3^2=9^2+7^2$ gives $r=6$, $s=2$, $t=5$, $u=4$.

Now, it's well-known that a number can be expressed as a sum of two squares if and only if primes of the form $4k+3$ appear with even exponents in its factorization. For the squares to be odd, the number must be a multiple of 2, but not of 4. To have more than one expression, there must be more than one prime divisor (counting multiplicity) of the form $4k+1$.

EDIT: There are infinitely many nontrivial solutions to $${r\choose3}+{s\choose3}={t\choose3}+{u\choose3}$$ In fact, there are infinitely many solutions to this equation with $t=u$. The following construction is due to W Sierpinski, Trois nombres tetraedraux en progression arithmetique, Elem Math 18 (1963) 54-55, MR 26 #4957, MR0147441.

Let $a_1=2$, $b_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=73a_n+148b_n$, $b_{n+1}=36a_n+73b_n$, $u_n=3b_n-a_n$, $v_n=4b_n$, $w_n=3b_n+a_n$. Then $${u_n+1\choose3}+{w_n+1\choose3}=2{v_n+1\choose3}$$ When $n=2$, this gives $${142\choose3}+{730\choose3}=2{581\choose3}$$ This gives infinitely many solutions, but by no means all solutions.

I've had a look at John Leech, Some solutions of Diophantine equations, Math Proc Camb Phil Soc 53 (1957) 778-780. For $n=3$, he found 985 solutions in integers smaller than 500. For $n=4$, he found 80 solutions in integers smaller than 500. For $n=5$, he found $${r\choose5}+{s\choose5}={t\choose5}+{u\choose5}$$ for $(r,s,t,u)=(118,117,133,78)$ and $(197,160,209,53)$ (as well as the trivial $(9,9,10,4)$), again going up to $500$. He found nothing nontrivial for $n\ge6$, although I don't know how far up he went for $n$ nor for $r,s,t,u$.

Computers have come along way since 1957. No doubt someone could push the calculations farther (or already has).

Comment: Here are a few nontrivial solutions to $${r\choose3}+{s\choose3}={t\choose3}+{u\choose3};$$ $(r,s,t,u)=(6,2,5,5), (10,6,9,8), (12,3,11,8), (12,6,10,10)$.

Comment: Great! Do you think that there is not a general way to determine $d$ given $a,b,c$ and any $n$?

Comment: For $n$=1, $d=a+b-c$, and $a+b>c$. For $n=2$, $d=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4(a+b-c)}}{2}$, and $a+b>c$, etc...

Comment: I don't see how that formula works for $n=2$, $\{\,a,b,c,d\,\}=\{\,8,3,6,6\,\}$. That is, your formula may give some solutions, but I don't think it gives all the solutions. And (as I wrote in the comments) for large $n$ (like $n\ge5$) I don't see why there should be any solutions at all.

Comment: True. There is a mistake in my formula. I correct it. Then I edit!

Comment: $$a^2+b^2=c^2$$
$$ a^2+a-a+b^2+b-b=c^2+c-c,$$
$$a(a+1)+b(b+1)=c(c+1)-c+a+b,$$
$$\frac{a(a+1)}{2}+\frac{b(b+1)}{2}=\frac{c(c+1),}{2}+\frac{a+b-c}{2},$$
$$
\binom{a+1}{2}+\binom{b+1}{2}=\binom{c+1}{2}+\frac{a+b-c}{2}.
$$
$$
\binom{a+2-1}{2}+\binom{b+2-1}{2}=\binom{c+2-1}{2}+\frac{a+b-c}{2}.
$$

Comment: We want $\frac{a+b-c}{2}=\binom{d+2-1}{2}$
$$
\frac{a+b-c}{2}=\frac{(d+1)(d+2)}{2}
$$
$$
d^2+3d+2-(a+b-c)=0
$$
$$
d_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{4(a+b-c)-1}}{2}.
$$
Then $d$ cannot be negative, hence my (corrected) formula. Sorry for the mistake, and thanks to pointing it out!

Comment: $$
d_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{4(a+b-c)+1}}{2},
$$ sorry!

Comment: Don't you want $(a+b-c)/2=d(d+1)/2$? But, no matter what, this is only going to give you the solutions that also satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$, and not all solutions satisfy that additional equation.

Comment: I see. The point is that I would like to see when it is possible to write a sum of _dispositions_ (like $a^k+b^k$) as a sum of _combinations_ (like $\binom{a+k-1}{k}+\binom{b+k-1}{k}$), and I started from the simplest, non-trivial example $a^2+b^2=c^2$. This led me to the idea of looking for the more general problem of making partitions of combinations.